# Request Sync always returns 404 : "Error: Requested entity was not found."

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm having a hard time implementing requestSync. It always returns

```
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
```

I use Node.js/Express for the backend. The linking/unlinking with the Google Home app work and my actions work as well. It's really the requestSync part that fails.

The closest ticket I've found, though not exactly the same,  [is this one](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/96).

Things I've tried

- agentUserId is a string, but if I pass it a number it returns a 400 with the message "Invalid value at 'agent_user_id'".
- tried sending agent_user_id instead of agentUserId, this returns a 404 the same error as when I send a agentUserId
- tried removing the "async:true" part of the body. did not notice a difference.
- during SYNC, hardcoded the value of the agentUserId to eliminate possibility that I'm sending the wrong one. I use that same agentUserId during requestSync and this fails.
- tried linking/unlinking multiple times in the google home app
- another interesting thing to note : when opening up the "Test Suite" from the actions on google console, I put in that same agentUserId + service account key, and it registers it well : I'm able to see my devices listed correctly. Which leads me to believe that my agentUserId is correct (this may be a false assumption)
- I'm 100% sure HomeGraph is enabled as I can see data on the charts in the "Overview" section of the HomeGraph API part of the console.

This is what the curl looks like (same as from the example)

```
curl -i -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{agent_us
er_id: \"1\"}" "https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSyn
c?key=API_KEY"
```

(my agentUserId is 1 in this case)

And this is what it looks like in code :

```
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSync?key=${config.googleApiKey}`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          agentUserId: String(userId),
          async: true,
        }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      },
    );
```

Regardless of what I do, the result is always :

```
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
```

I don't know where else to look to identify this problem. Any pointers would help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

It wasn't too far from [the one I had posted above](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/96). Although my problem is that when I generated an API key, the google home cloud console opened the wrong project by default. I had the wrong API key all along.

Comment: My account is a verified billing account.But still I am facing the same issue. Can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167163/unable-to-execute-rest-api-via-curl)?